# CQRS: Should the ICommandHandler<TCommand> be responsible for calling SaveChanges() on the IUnitOfWork?

Tags: unit-of-work, cqrs

Let's say I have a command handler:

```
public class AddNewUserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<AddNewUserCommand>
{
    //IUserManagementUnitOfWork implements IUnitOfWork.SaveChanges()
    //hold references to related repositories
    //basically an abstraction over DbContext/DbSet
    private IUserManagementUnitOfWork uow; 

    public AddNewUserCommandHandler(IUserManagementUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        this.uow = uow;
    }

    public void Handle(AddNewUserCommand command)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            FirstName = command.FirstName,
            LastName = command.LastName
        };
        uow.UserRepository.Add(user);
        uow.SaveChanges(); //should this be here?
        command.UserId = user.Id;
    }
}
```

My question is: should the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` be responsible for calling `SaveChanges()` on the `IUnitOfWork`? or should this be the responsibility of the caller?

For example, the `AddNewUserCommandHandler` would only have the `IRepository<User>` as its dependency, and the caller would hold reference to the `IUnitOfWork` and call `SaveChanges()` when it feels like it. The caller might be an `ICommandProcessor` that can process multiple `ICommand`s and call `SaveChanges` when all commands are handled by its handlers successfully.

Or, leave the `SaveChanges()` duty to the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` and wrap the batch command processor in a `TransactionScope`, and delegate `command.UserId = user.Id` to an event that will execute after calling `TransactionScope.Complete()`.

Which approach is the better one?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion with this?

Comment: I've decided to leave the `SaveChanges()` method in the command handler, then wrap the `Handle(query)` method with `TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator`, `PostTransactionCommandHandlerDecorator`, and `CommandHandlerExceptionDecorator`, respectively. The caller can wrap multiple commands in another `TransactionScope` if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a setup that's quite similar to the [ddd-cqrs-sample](https://code.google.com/p/ddd-cqrs-sample/wiki/CommandQueryResponsibilitySegregationSystemArchitectMentaModel#Run_Environment). There's a class for the "run environment" that's responsible for running commands with the corresponding command handlers. Besides this my RE implements the **transaction boundary**. It's responsible for starting a unit of work and do a commit/rollback after command execution depending on the command's result.

Of course this depends on your use case. If your commands behave much the same, perhaps your calling class can make up the transaction boundary. I think in most cases one should try to establish such a command design in order to have commands that are simple and focussed on one task.